# Java Micronaut Data generates fake column

Tags: java, orm, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have two Java Entites Obj and Trt for two tables in DB obj ( ID, ID_TRT,...) and trt(ID,...) defined as following:

```
@MappedEntity("obj")
public class ObjEntity{

...
private TrtEntity trt;
...

@Nullable
    @MappedProperty("ID_TRT")
    @JoinColumn(name ="ID_TRT")
    @Relation(value = Relation.Kind.MANY_TO_ONE)
    public TraitementEntity getTrt() {
        return trt;
    }

    public void setTrt(final TrtEntity trt) {
        this.trt= trt;
    }
...
}


@MappedEntity("trt")
public class TrtEntity{

private Long id;
private List<ObjEntity> objs;
....
@Relation(value = Relation.Kind.ONE_TO_MANY, mappedBy = "trt", cascade = { Relation.Cascade.ALL })
    public List<ObjEntity> getObjs() {
        return objs;
    }
...
}
```

In a class, we call a method ObjRepository.findAll(...), which should execute the following SQL query:

```
select ID, ID_TRT, .... from obj where ...
```

Sometimes we get this query, but sometimes we have :

```
select ID, TRT_ID, .... from obj where ...
```

The problem is that **ID_TRT** becomes **TRT_ID** in generated query by Micronaut Data

Any idea?

Comment: Have you grepped your entire codebase for `ID_TRT`? Have you completely cleaned and rebuilt the project?

Comment: Yes I have cleaned and rebuilt the project.
I don't understand the first part of the question?
Thank you.